# Angular Ionic ion-datetime picker

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I got problem to code time picker with min and max hour from 10:00 am to 10:00 pm. Unfortunately, this cannot be achieved using the **ion-datetime**. Is there anything else I can do? This is my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-jrfrvz) demo code

HTML

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="hh:mm A" 
                [(ngModel)]="myDate" 
                (ionChange)="setDate()" min="10:00" max="20:00"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

**Component**

```
myDate; minDate;maxDate;
  datesArray = [];

  constructor() {

      this.minDate = '2020-08-28 10:00';
      this.maxDate = '2020-08-28 20:00'
  }

  setDate() {

    this.minDate = this.myDate;
    this.datesArray.push(this.myDate);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ion-content padding>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime display-timezone="ist" displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A" 
                [(ngModel)]="minDate" 
                (ionChange)="setDate()"   hourValues="10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>


</ion-content>



import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { max } from 'rxjs/operator/max';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  myDate: any;
  minDate: any;
  maxDate: any;
  datesArray = [];

  constructor(private navController: NavController) {
    
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myDate = new Date();
    const minDate = new Date();
    minDate.setHours(10, 0, 0, 0);
    this.minDate = minDate.toISOString();
    const maxDate = new Date();
    maxDate.setHours(22, 0, 0, 0);
    this.maxDate = maxDate.toISOString();
  }

  setDate() {
    this.minDate = this.myDate;
    this.datesArray.push(this.myDate);
  }
}
```

Here is working Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3y23qf